# Added new account to Apple Mail, it can't authenticate though webmail works fine

Tags: mail.app, email, imap, smtp

I'm out of ideas on what to try here.  2018 MBP running Mojave 10.14.6.

I just received a new work email address, that was just created and has never been used before.  I have numerous other email addresses on this machine including Gmail, iCloud (me.com), and personal domains that all work perfectly well using IMAP/SMTP.

This address just refuses to authenticate.  The password is correct, everything is correct and in fact works perfectly at the host's webmail portal (hosts.co.uk).

Specifically in Connection Doctor I get:

```
WROTE Jan 15 17:42:49.136 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.hosts.co.uk -- port:143 -- socket:0x600002192100 -- thread:0x6000050c7a00
8.1138 LOGIN my_login_id ********

READ Jan 15 17:42:59.137 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.hosts.co.uk -- port:143 -- socket:0x600002192100 -- thread:0x6000050c7a00
8.1138 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.

WROTE Jan 15 17:42:59.137 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1_2] -- host:imap.hosts.co.uk -- port:143 -- socket:0x600002192100 -- thread:0x6000050c7a00
9.1138 LOGOUT
```

I've tried everything I can think of including manual (Advanced) settings for port, different SMTP account selections, enabling "less secure apps" on Google (since I'd like to use them for SMTP), confirming Google's "I'm really me" CAPTCHA, and a host of other stuff I can't even remember at this moment.

This is my only address that fails to work, and in fact the only address I've ever had not "just work" and I've been using Mail since the beginning.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the host allow IMAP?  Does the host require per-app passwords?

Comment: What does your employer's IT support say? Can you connect without using Google's SMTP?

Comment: TLS on port 143?

Comment: Host allows IMAP, password is correct and works fine in their webmail client.  We are a tiny company so there is no "IT Support" but we know our tech and are all scratching out heads at the moment.  Cannot connect with ANY SMTP, Google or otherwise.  TLS port 143 is the default yes, just for kicks I've tried the other usual suspects but no joy yet.

Comment: Something I've seen with IMAP is that providing a full email address instead of just the part prior to the @ can make a difference.

Comment: Yep have tried it both ways just in case but no joy.  I also tried my actual "username" which is completely different from the email address but of course that didn't work, and I didn't actually expect it to since it explicitly demands an email address.

Comment: So I just tried the full email address as the username again (I'm sure I tried it before but might have also changed something else at the same time so... who knows) and it works now.  So despite the host giving me a "username", mail doesn't like that username and wants the email address instead.